# How to check variable with line break

Tags: batch

I'm writing this script and I need it to check if some drives are connected, for that I'm using `fsutil fsinfo drives` and I'm saving the output in a var. Then, I check with an 'if' if the var is what I need.

However, the output begins with a blank like and I don't know how to write that in the if, it should be something like `IF %drives% NEQ "-blank line-Drives: C:\ D:\"`

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally did that by using:

`FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('fsutil fsinfo drives') DO set drives=%%i`

`echo %drives% | find "Drives: C:\ D:\ E:\ F:\ G:\ H:\" >NUL`

`if %errorlevel% == 1 (`